# 'You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.' even with Bundler 2.0.2 installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to Dockerize my Rails app and constantly getting this warning when running `docker build -t tml_portal`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  355.1MB
Step 1/1 : FROM rails:onbuild
# Executing 4 build triggers
 ---> Using cache
 ---> Using cache
 ---> Running in 641c1404bf87
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 20
```

I've tried `bundler update --system`, `gem uninstall bundler`, `gem install bundler 2.0.2`, etc. Basically every suggestion on the internet. I will say that I have a problem sometimes where if I switch directories, `RVM` switches to `ruby 2.3.3` and I have to `rvm use 2.6.5`. My system ruby is not the same as local. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but I just can't figure out a solution. I've also made sure to delete the Docker build cache.

Comment: Do you have the ruby version specified somewhere in the project like a `.ruby-version` file or the Gemfile?

Comment: Shouldn't `bundler update --system` be `bundle update --bundler`? The same for `gem install bundler 2.0.2` which should be `gem install bundler -v 2.0.2`.

Comment: I have Ruby version 2.6.5 in my Gem file

Comment: I've tried those commands too. Still the same error. Maybe I need to reinstall Docker. I had this nightmare with trying to deploy to Heroku and AWS as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom of your `Gemfile.lock` it should say what version of Bundler was used:

```rb
# Gemfile.lock

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

You can also check what version of Bundler you're currently using in the console with:

```
bundler -v
```

Make sure both of those have the version you're looking for. If not, delete the `Gemfile.lock` completely and - barring you have the updated version installed - it should re-bundle with the updated version.

Comment: Oh trust me, I've done all that. I've been corresponding with one of the developers of Bundler. I've uninstalled all versions of Ruby and RVM. I'm using rbenv now. This person suggested a beta version of Bundler they're working on. Still no luck yet but will report back.